# Why does accessing a missing getter in Typescript return 'undefined' rather than cause a compilation error?

Tags: typescript, getter-setter

When writing a property setter in Typescript it's not required to include a getter at the same time:

```
set name(name: string)
{
    ... 
}
```

However when accessing the corresponding property getter via `this.name` (which isn't defined) it is not a compile time error and returns the value `undefined`. I can't understand why and I also can't find any discussion about it.

```
const theName = this.name;   // undefined at runtime, but typed as 'string'
```

I'm most likely to end up in this situation accidentally and it can waste a lot of time in the rare case where I don't immediately notice.

The 'traditional' way to define a property is like this, so maybe that explains why the decision was made.

```
Object.defineProperty(Dog.prototype, "name", {
    set: function (name) {
    },
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: true
});
```

Wishful thinking of course but I'd **much** rather the behavior was to return the original 'raw' value passed in - that would be amazing. And avoid this awful mess :-/

```
set name(name: string)
{
   this._name = name;
   doNameStuff(name);
}
get name() 
{
   return this._name;
}
private _name!: string;
```

Comment: Because TypeScript has no concept of `writeonly` properties (see [microsoft/TypeScript#21759](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21759) and [microsoft/TypeScript#30852](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30852)), nor does it currently allow a way to say that the get and set behavior of a property are unrelated in type (see [microsoft/TypeScript#43362](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43662)). It's basically a missing feature and apparently not a high priority because setter-only types don't seem to be very common.

Comment: @jcalz I came across the discussions about differing types, but this just seems like a separate compile time bug. Why not enforce both having to be defined? I suppose they're effectively saying if you really want a write only property your getter is automatically broken - and if you forget or make a typo you're on your own!

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30852#issuecomment-902210465 is relevant

Comment: @jcalz You can see why I didn't find that issue by title! I'll check out the linter rule too.

Comment: I suppose I'll write up an answer pointing to this stuff, if that seems reasonable.

Comment: I don't know if I should address the part where a getterless setter is the same as a getter that somehow remembers the value passed into the getter.  TS compiles to JS and JS does not work this way, so it would be a non-starter to ask TS to  output extra JS (see [TS Design Non-Goal #6](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals#non-goals))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is a soundness hole in TypeScript.  The compiler is happy to let you write a `set` property accessor without a corresponding `get` accessor, but it does not model the resulting behavior of the property very well.  Conceptually a property with a setter but no getter should be "`writeonly`" in the same way that a property with a getter but no setter is [`readonly`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#readonly-properties).  Indeed, if you write a getter but no setter, the compiler infers that the property is `readonly`:

```
const foo = {
    get bar() { return 1 }
}
/* const foo: {
    readonly bar: number;
} */
```

But there is currently no such thing as `writeonly` in TypeScript, and the compiler instead models such a property as being a normal read-write property:

```
const baz = {
    set qux(x: number) { }
}
/* const baz: {
    qux: number;
} */
```

There is a longstanding open issue asking for `writeonly` properties at [microsoft/TypeScript#21759](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21759) but it's not clear if or when it will ever be addressed.

TypeScript 4.3 introduced some support for [variant accessors](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-3.html#separate-write-types-on-properties) which allows the type system to model getter and setter types that are different.  But currently there's a requirement that the getter type needs to be assignable to the setter type.  You can't express that the setter accepts (say) `number` but the getter always produces `undefined`.  So there's another open issue at  [microsoft/TypeScript#43662](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43662) asking for unrelated types in the setter and getter.  If implemented, that would be another way to model getterless setters; reading the property would be known to always produce `undefined`.  Again, though, it's not clear that this will be implemented.

And there have been some suggestions to just have getterless setters be a compiler error, such as [microsoft/TypeScript#30852](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30852) but this looks like it would be declined because it would be a breaking change for existing TypeScript code... although in my view it would only break code that already does weird things. But I'm not in charge.

Anyway, as I [mentioned in a comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30852#issuecomment-902210465), the only suggestion I could think of for now is for someone to use [ESLint's accessor-pairs](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/accessor-pairs) linter rule.  This rule will complain if you forget the getter, so at least you'd be forced to write safer code.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEMC8MDeAoG2YHMCmsARgIYBOAFAJToxmECuZYMAjDAL4ZcD0AVDFCRYCEAC50WHPRIATcABsAnjFJkJYBgFsi+MgG5uMPjwwYh0VSQBeKSThgRCMAI4MAHhXcbtusjTRObgx+QXBLUmsJTAc3bxhNHT1DDmMeIA)

Comment: I think with 30852 it's probably the existing code that would be the deal breaker for sure. But (as you implied) unless you try to read the value then it's not an error. The error therefore would only need to occur if you simultaneously 'forgot' your getter AND tried to use it. My favorite solution: an automatic 'implicit' getter that simply returns your original 'raw' value isn't going to happen :-( but if it ever did it would probably make a lot of people very happy.

Comment: I think if you want to see such implicit getters you should ask for it from JavaScript and then TypeScript would eventually get it.  TS is pretty much out of the game of introducing new runtime functionality... they got burned with `enum` and they're not going to do it again.